pac4j v6 replacement of Pac4JHttpServletRequestWrapper
i'm migrating from an old version of pac4j to the v6,
i use the SecurityLogic.perform method and in the docs
https://www.pac4j.org/docs/how-to-implement-pac4j-for-a-new-framework.html
and https://www.pac4j.org/blog/what_s_new_in_pac4j_v6.html
it's written to use Pac4JHttpServletRequestWrapper
but it doesn't exist anymore
what is the replacement of Pac4JHttpServletRequestWrapper class?
config.getSecurityLogic().perform(config, (ctx, session, profiles) -> { filterChain.doFilter(profiles.isEmpty() ? request : new Pac4JHttpServletRequestWrapper(request, profiles), response); return null; }, clientSamlService.getClient().getClass().getSimpleName(), null, null, new JEEFrameworkParameters(request, response));
thanks !
i tried to just put request but in the end i've got a null profile

ok got it, i was lost in the docs...
all i need is to import the right dependencies...
https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j/wiki/Dependencies
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakartaee-pac4j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1</version>
</dependency>
dependency>
    <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>pac4j-saml</artifactId>
</dependency>

